# Need help formally showing $[0,1)$ is a closed set in $(-1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to show that the interval $[0,1)$ is a closed subset of $(-1,1)$ by using the definition that a closed subset contains all of its limit points.
So for a convergent sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $[0,1)$ we have that $0 \leq x_{n} < 1$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$.  How can I show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_{n} = x$ implies that $x \in [0,1)$? I understand that 1 cannot be a limit point of $[0,1)$ since $1 \not\in (-1,1)$ but I'm having a hard time saying that in a formal way?

Comment: Note that any element of $(-1,1)$ **must** satisfy $-1 < x <1$. Hence if $x_n \to x$ then you must have $-1 < x < 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $1$ is not in the adherence, observe that $$(1-\varepsilon,1)\cap (-1,1)=\emptyset.$$
In other words, there is no sequence of $[0,1)$ that converge to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed an important part of the definition which made the problem harder. The statement you want to prove is for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $[0,1)$ such that
$$\lim_n x_n = x \quad \text{ for some } x\in (-1,1),$$ 
then we must have $x\in [0,1)$.